# What does this 意識 refer to?

Tags: meaning, word-requests

Context: a guy complaining about his boss with a colleague.

振り回されて意識せざるを得ない

I don't know how to translate the sentence due to the 意識. I have two interpretations

I cannot help being controlled/jerked around (by the boss) and be conscious (about the fact he's being controlled)

I cannot help being controlled/jerked around (by the boss) and be conscious (of the boss)

Which would be correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [We usually don't need 7 pages](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57748/5010) to understand the context, but this time it's difficult to directly answer your question because of the lack of the context... Your citation says nothing about the boss.

Answer (score 3):

I think it refers to his boss.

It would mean "I can't help being conscious of my boss because I am controlled(swayed) by him(her)".

If it means "conscious about the fact he's being controlled", it would be 振り回されていることを意識せざるを得ない.

Answer (score 2):

> 振り回されて意識せざるを得ない。
>   I am at the mercy (of someone/something), *so* I can't help being conscious.

This te-form is [for describing a reason](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html). The sentence says nothing explicitly about what this person is conscious of. It may be the boss, what the boss said, or something completely different depending on the previous context.

Comment: I think  I alrady got it, my main problem was that I didn't get if it referred to 振り回され, but you and Tam's replies helped. But why are you using the verb in past? I don't see the past form here..

Comment: There's the passive in 振り回され right? that would make it I am swayed by (someone), rather than I was swayed/at the mercy of someone

Comment: @Daniel Yes it should've been in present tense.